# Downloaded Jekyll website from Github and it doesnt serve Locally

Tags: github, jekyll

I created a website with Jekyll and uploaded it to github. This allowed me to host my site for free (It's mostly just a template at the moment) repo here:

https://github.com/themallardcomplexion/themallardcomplexion.github.io

It serves fine online with the domain name but I tried to download it and serve it locally but get the following errors:

Configuration file: none
            Source: C:/Users/isw/Desktop/Taijisoce/themallardcomplexion.github.io-master
       Destination: C:/Users/isw/Desktop/Taijisoce/themallardcomplexion.github.io-master/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
     Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in themallardcomplexion.github.io-master/_posts/2019-01-19-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'default' requested in themallardcomplexion.github.io-master/404.html does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'page' requested in themallardcomplexion.github.io-master/about.md does not exist.
     Build Warning: Layout 'home' requested in themallardcomplexion.github.io-master/index.md does not exist.
                    done in 0.587 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/isw/Desktop/Taijisoce/themallardcomplexion.github.io-master'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.

It serves with no formatting and just shows a plain text site....  any ideas?

I have tried downloading the code via the Github app and downloading it as zip

Comment: You are (probably) missing the theme in your local installation. That is why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are coming from Jekyll looking for layouts for the pages you built. You need to make a `/_layouts/` folder with all the layouts your site needs:

```
/_layouts/
  |
  |--default.html
  |
  |--post.html
  |
  |--page.html
  |
```

These all correspond to the build warnings that are coming up. See the Jekyll [tutorials](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/) and [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/layouts/) for more details.

Also, instead of downloading the repo, it's better to clone it. That way you can work on changes locally then push changes to GitHub. Here's the link to docs for [cloning a repo](https://help.github.com/en/articles/cloning-a-repository)

Comment: Thanks, I think your last paragraph was where the problem lay. I didnt know downloading was different from cloning. Now its created another problem haha but this is a good starting point. Thank you!